# How to open a page, retrieve data and close it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for the first time and was wondering how to retrieve data from a page (say, page2)

```
document.getElementById("result_box").innerText;
```

while staying on page1, and using a content script that needs the result from page 2.

For example, highlighting the text and clicking the little extension icon would turn the word into french. page2, in this case, is google translate.

https://translate.google.com.au/#en/fr/whateverwordhere

And the actual stuff is done by a content script on the page1, where I would be typing.

This question is just about how to open, retrieve and close (or not open and close, just retrieve) data from a separate page.

Comment: There should be existing answers that show how to use the background page script to open a tab, inject a content script, get the data via messaging, open another page.

Comment: Try [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as it lets you use the simple API for one-time requests and a more complex API that allows you to have long-lived connections for exchanging multiple messages with a shared context. It is also possible to send a message to another extension if you know its ID, which is covered in the cross-extension messages section.